# Value of finite alternating sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a chance to calculate the value of the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{500}(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{1+1/n}-1\right)$$
by hand?

I've tried to rewrite the sequence via the binomial series, but I failed. Other attempts, i.e. to split the sum in a positive and a negativ part, weren't successful.

So the question came up: How to calculate the sum if it is at all possible?

Comment: You can drop the $-1$ inside the bracket at you will have $250$ lots of each of $+1$ and $-1$. Aside from that it doesn't simplify - even with [technology](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+500+of+(-1)%5En(Sqrt(1%2B1%2Fn)-1)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{500}(-1)^n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)&=&\sum_{k=1}^{250}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2k+1}{2k}}-\sqrt{\frac{2k}{2k-1}}\right)\\&=&-\sum_{k=1}^{250}\int_{2k-1}^{2k}\frac{dt}{2t\sqrt{t^2+t}}\\&=&-\sum_{k=1}^{250}\int_{4k-2}^{4k}\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t^2+2t}}\end{eqnarray*} $$
can be approximated through:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}-\sum_{k\geq 1}\int_{4k-2}^{4k}\frac{dt}{t(t+1)}=-\sum_{k\geq 1}\log\left(\frac{4k(4k-1)}{(4k-2)(4k+1)}\right) &=& -\log\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{4k(4k-1)}{(4k-2)(4k+1)}\\&=&\log(4\sqrt{2\pi})-2\log\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\\&\approx&-0.27.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: +1 So -0.270812, compared with the answer from simply doing the sum (using Mathematica) of -0.277844, so within 3%.